# A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove). No clue why

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am making a simple game in the console using some of the tricks from the youtuber JavidX9. Everything displays correctly when the window and buffer size are correct, FYI for anyone that tries to run it. My issue comes about when I try to close the application when debugging it. Sometimes if I mess with it enough by moving the character around the screen randomly it will break. The error I get is the one listed in the title. But after that, I get a linker error that tells me that the process is still running ( which I can not find ). So it is a nightmare to debug. I have been searching for the answer to this issue for several days now, hopefully, one of you C++ gods can help me out. The code is pretty short.

EDIT: Just found out some new information. If i start the program, and do nothing at all, it will crash after about a minute or so. Potential Thread problems?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int screenWidth = 120; //Console Screen Size. X = Cols & Y = Rows
int screenHeight = 40;

int mapWidth = 48;  //World Dimensions
int mapHeight = 48;

int playerX = mapWidth / 2;
int playerY = mapHeight / 2;

int main()
{
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[screenWidth * screenHeight];
    HANDLE consoleHandle = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(consoleHandle);
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    // 16 x 3


    wstring map;          //^
    map += L"################################################";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#.......########........########........########";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"###............#.##............#.##............#";
    map += L"##.............#.#.............#.#.............#";
    map += L"#......####..###.......####..###.......####..###";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......#########.......#########.......#########";
    map += L"#..............#...............................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#.......########........########........########";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"###............#.##............#.##............#";
    map += L"##.............#.#.............#.#.............#";
    map += L"#......####..###.......####..###.......####..###";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......#########.......#########.......#########";
    map += L"#..............#...............................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#..............................................#";
    map += L"#.......########........########........########";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#......##......#.......##......#.......##......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"###............#.##............#.##............#";
    map += L"##.............#.#.............#.#.............#";
    map += L"#......####..###.......####..###.......####..###";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#......#.......#.......#.......#.......#.......#";
    map += L"#..............#...............#...............#";
    map += L"#......#########.......#########.......#########";
    map += L"#..............#...............................#";
    map += L"################################################";

    const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 20;
    const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
    const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

    DWORD next_game_tick = GetTickCount();
    int loops;
    bool game_is_running = true;

    while (game_is_running)
    {
        loops = 0;

        while (GetTickCount() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP)
        {
            // Update
            for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth * screenHeight; i++)
            {
                screen[i] = ' ';
            }

            if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'A'))
            {
                if (map[(playerX - 1) + mapWidth * playerY] == '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerX--;
                }
            }


            if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'D'))
            {
                if (map[(playerX + 1) + mapWidth * playerY] == '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerX++;
                }
            }

            if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'S'))
            {
                if (map[playerX + mapWidth * (playerY + 1)] == '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerY++;
                }
            }

            if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'W'))
            {
                if (map[playerX + mapWidth * (playerY - 1)] == '#')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerY--;
                }
            }


            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }

        // Draw the map to the buffer
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                screen[x + screenWidth * y] = map[x + mapWidth * y];
            }
            screen[playerX + screenWidth * playerY] = '@'; // Draw the player
        }

        // Display the Buffer
        screen[screenWidth * screenHeight - 1] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(consoleHandle, screen, screenWidth * screenHeight, { 0,0 }, &bytesWritten);
    }
}
```

Comment: `map` is a dangerous name for a variable for someone using namespace std.

Comment: You are right. Did not think about it since i was making this to test something. I will change that. Thanks.

Comment: @scohe001 Only if they aren't practising safe c++; never let your `std`s out.

Comment: You can start by verifying whether you're accessing elements outside the bounds of the `map` string.  You can do that by using `at()` to access the elements.  Also use `std::vector ` instead of `new/delete` -- then you can use the same technique of using the `at` call.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, ill give that a shot. Hopefully, I can implement that correctly, but I also am starting to wonder if it is something to do with threads (see edit on the original post). Someone in my discord chat mentioned that, I have no experience with threads. Do you see anything there that would have cause thread issues?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. My map array being bigger than my screen array was causing the issue somehow. I cannot explain in depth how this was causing the error, but it was. After adding a 2d camera, locking it to the player coordinates, and clamping it to the border of the map array it works just fine now. I have a whole set of other issues to deal with now, but this one can be marked as solved. If someone else can explain the in depth reason as to why this was the issue that would be amazing. Thanks.